# create matrix with row length L from 1D vector

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

suppose that we have following 1D array

```
x(1),x(2),......x(n)
```

where n is length of sample,and  suppose that we want  create matrix  consisting from this elements using following rule,using  some parameter L,our two dimensional array consists by following   elements

```
(1 row) x(1),x(2),.....x(l)
(2 row)  x(2),x(3),.....x(l+1)
(3 row) x(3),x(4),.......x(l+2)
.
.
.
.(m row)  x(m),x(m+1).... x(n)
```

i have tried following code

```
function [ x ]=create_matrix(b,n,L)
for i=1:n/2 
    x(i,end)=b(i:L);
end;
```

where b is  input  1D   vector,n is length(b),L is   matrix  row length,but when i run this code,i got following error

```
??? Undefined function or variable "x".

Error in ==> create_matrix at 4
    x(i,end)=b(i:L);
```

maybe something wrong declaration of two dimensional array in  matlab,or something else?actually i know  that it is very simple for implement,but  i could not it myself,please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code:

```
function [ x ]=create_matrix(b,l)
    n = length(b);
    m = n-l+1;
    x = zeros(m,l);
    for i=1:m
        x(i,:)=b(i:i+l-1);
    end;
end
```

Example:

```
EDU>> create_matrix(1:10,4)

ans =

     1     2     3     4
     2     3     4     5
     3     4     5     6
     4     5     6     7
     5     6     7     8
     6     7     8     9
     7     8     9    10
```

Also, this matrix is a flipped toeplitz matrix. So the same thing can be achieved with:

```
fliplr(toeplitz(4:10,4:-1:1))
```

Output:

```
ans =

     1     2     3     4
     2     3     4     5
     3     4     5     6
     4     5     6     7
     5     6     7     8
     6     7     8     9
     7     8     9    10
```

Comment: aa yes,because as much we change l,m would be changed yes i see

Comment: @dato also, a more efficient implementation would probably be to assign the columns to x instead of the rows as I have above. This is because MATLAB is column major.

Comment: yes for what  i need it,does not matter  it would   be row major order or column major,important  is that it should be non square for  singular value decomposition.thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

Another option (probably faster in performance) is to use `bsxfun`, for example

```
m=7;
l=4;
bsxfun(@plus,[1:m]',0:l-1)

ans =
 1     2     3     4
 2     3     4     5
 3     4     5     6
 4     5     6     7
 5     6     7     8
 6     7     8     9
 7     8     9    10
```

or for a generic vector `x` use

```
x(bsxfun(@plus,x(1:m)',0:x(l-1)))
```

Comment: If `x` is a random vector I'm not sure this method will work.

Comment: I think it will, because the `bsxfun` solution is for the index of `x`, so for `x` just do `x(bsxfun(@...) )